# unusual spike in the response time in azure app-service

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-appservice

Currently my app service in azure performs well in staging environments but when it comes to production i find an unusual spike in the response times in application and demands for app-service restart in a few scenarios.
I am trying to analyse this issue and was trying to generate a thread dump using the kudu lite but the container is crashing when we try this and i am currently working with Microsoft on this.
Meanwhile what are the best practices or approach to understand this . I have tried to dig in the application insights logs but there was no much info about the worker threads that are hung up or if the thread pool is exhausted .
Please advise me on this situation on how to analyse and reverse engineer to get to the bottom of this problem .
Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app service plan check the **Diagnosed and solve problems**” analyze CPU usage of your App on all instances and see a breakdown of usage of all apps on your server. And check the CPU utilization on each instance serving your app and identify the app and the corresponding process causing High CPU in percentage. Check the [Troubleshoot performance degradation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-performance-degradation) of our service

[image]

You can use the **Kudu** console to download the **Diagnostic dump** in a **KUDU -> Tools -> Diagnostic dump**

[image]

Once you download the **diagnostic dump** you have **log files** and a **Deployment** directory.

You can check the log files to know the spike details

[image]

Refer [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-websites-online-tools-you-should-know-about/) for more information